# cin is not accepting input with space in them in C++?

Tags: c++, iostream, cin

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string doi, name, address, phone;
    cout<<"Please provide these credentials:\n";
    cout<<"1.Date of issue\n";
    cin>>doi;
    cout<<"2.Name\n";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"3.Address\n";
    cin>>address;
    cout<<"4.Phone Number\n\n";
    cin>>phone;
    return 0;
}
```

When I am giving name input with spaces, for eg ("John Doe"), instead of storing this value is name it split value by space and store "John" in name and "Doe" in address.

Comment: Huh? Of course not.... `std::cin` stops reading input at the first whitespace encountered....

Comment: Off topic: Avoid naming like `doi` for `date of issue`; Instead, according to camelCase naming convention, you can use: dateOfIssue.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- it's not `std::cin` that's the culprit here. It's the stream extractors (`operator>>`) that stop reading on whitespace. Other readers (`std::getline() being the most common) don't.

Answer (score 3):

If you have spaces in the string you want to read, you could use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) like this:

```
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

*instead* of the line:

```
std::cin >> name;
```

Note that the `getline` will read all characters up to a newline character.

Also, please avoid `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Value stored in name is corresponding to the last word in my input. For eg, If my input = "John Doe", then only Doe is stored in my name variable.

Comment: Are each of the fields in the input on separate lines?

Comment: string doi, name, address, phone;
cout<<"Please provide these credentials:\n";
cout<<"1.Date of issue\n";
cin>>doi;
cout<<"2.Name\n";
cin>>name;
std::getline(std::cin, name);
cout<<"3.Address\n";
cin>>address;
cout<<"4.Phone Number\n";
cin>>phone;
cout<<"name"<<name;

Comment: Edited the answer. replace the `cin` with a `getline`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use getline() in place of cin when you need to input strings with spaces.
In your case the syntax will be

```
string name;
getline(cin,name);
```

for more info on getline https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getline-string-c/

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of muddled terminology in the comments and the answers. `std::cin` is an **object**; it doesn't **do anything** on its own.

**Functions** that read from input streams fit into one of two categories: they do *formatted input* or *unformatted input*. Formatted input functions translate the **text** that they get from the input stream (here, `std::cin`) into the data type that they're trying to read:

```
int i;
std::cin >> i; // operator>> reads text and translates it into an integer value
```

Formatted input functions begin by skipping whitespace, then they read characters and translate them; when the function encounters a character that isn't valid for the type that they're reading, or when they see whitespace, they stop. So in the example above, if you typed " 32 ", the stream extractor would skip the leading space, read the `3` and the `2`, see the following space, and stop reading. The value stored into `i` would be 32.

```
std::string data;
std::cin >> data;
```

Here, if you type "Hello, world", the stream extractor (`operator>>`) will read up to the space, and store `"Hello,"` in `data`.

If you want to read whitespace as well as non-whitespace you need an unformatted input function:

```
std::string data;
std::getline(std::cin, data);
```

Here, the call to `getline` reads text from `std::cin` up to the first newline character or to the end of the input stream. So if you typed " 32 " for this code, `data` would hold the text `" 32 "`. If you typed "Hello, world", `data` would hold the text `"Hello, world"`.

And note that if you mix formatted input functions with unformatted input functions you have to be careful about leftover whitespace:

```
int i;
std::string data;
std::cin >> i;
std::getline(std::cin, data);
```

If you typed "32 Hello, world" on a single line, `i` would get the 32, and `data` would get " Hello, world".

On the other hand, if you type two lines of input, the first with "32" and the second with "Hello, world", you'll get 32 in `i`, but `data` will be empty. That's because the stream extractor read the `3` and the `2`, then saw a newline character, and stopped, leaving the newline in the input buffer. `std::getline` then read that newline character and it, too, stopped. But it read the entire line: it swallowed the newline character.

So when your code switches from formatted input to unformatted you have to deal with whitespace characters remaining in the input buffer. If you want to read them, fine; but if you don't, you need to remove them:

```
int i;
std::string data;
std::cin >> i;
std::getline(std::cin, data); // read the rest of the line
std::getline(std::cin, data); // read the next line of text
```

A better approach is to do that cleanup with something like `std::cin.ignore(42, '\n');`. `std::ignore` is an unformatted input function; in this call it reads up to 42 characters, looking for a newline character. It stops reading when it has read 42 characters, sees a newline character, or hits the end of the input. That's better than using `std::getline(std::cin, data)` because it doesn't store the text into `data`, which could require a bunch of resizing if there's a lot of text in the remainder of the line. The more usual form for that call is to pass `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` as the size argument; that's a special case, and it puts no limit on the number of characters to be read. So `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');` will read characters until it finds a newline or hits the end of the input.

```
int i;
std::string data;
std::cin >> i;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n'); // flush the rest of the line
std::getline(std::cin, data); // read the next line of text
```